# presentModalViewController fails to show up if label added

Tags: ios, presentmodalviewcontroller, lldb

I'm trying to add a Modal ViewController to the existing application. To init and open it I use the following code

```
AddedViewController *addedOne = [[AddedViewController alloc] init];
[self.parent presentModalViewController:addedOne animated:YES];
```

If AddedViewController.xib with a View inside of course is just empty it opens nicely,

but

This throws SIGTRAP signal ((lldb) in log) at loading if  AddedViewController.xib is not empty (i.e.) even if I add just a UILabel with static text there.

How can I handle this to have fully-operational ViewController (with labels, buttons, textfields, etc.. open properly?

========

UPD.
Problem easily resolved, see my answer below. =)

Comment: I think your question is incomplete. It ends in 'What'!

Comment: @Surfbutler oh, yes. Sudden Skype call, fixed. Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are trying to present this inside the current view, you should not use `self.parent` and just use `self`.

Comment: I'm trying to present in instead of current view, which is the child of a main program view, that's why `.parent` is used.

Comment: Anyway, if I change to just `self` it behaves the same way - ok to load empty ViewController and SIGTRAP if I add even a Label therein.

Comment: If you are only aborting when you assign something to the label, then my guess is the label isn't configured quite right. I would look there and track down the issue with that.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was in **Use Autolayout** checkbox for the ViewController settings, now everything works fine TWIMC. =))